# Where should I locate logic related to layout in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-layout

I need to customize the attributes of my body tag. Where should I locate the logic? In a Base Controller, view Helper ?

This should be the layout

```
<?=$this->doctype() ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body<?=$this->bodyAttrs?>>  <!-- or <?=$this->bodyAttrs()?> -->
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

And this should be the variables declaration in controllers

```
class Applicant_HomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->idBody = "someId1";
        $this->classesBody = array("wide","dark");
    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        $this->idBody = "someId2";
        $this->classesBody = array();
    }

    public function signUpAction()
    {
        $this->idBody = "someId3";
        $this->classesBody = array("no-menu","narrow");
    }
}
```

This is the function where the attributes are concatenated.

```
/**
  * @param string $idBody     id Attribute
  * @param array $classesBody class Attribute (array of strings)
  */
protected function _makeBodyAttribs($idBody,$classesBody)
{
    $id = isset($idBody)?' id="'.$idBody.'"':'';
    $hasClasses = isset($classesBody)&&count($classesBody);
    $class = $hasClasses?' class="'.implode(' ',$classesBody).'"':'';
    return $id.$class;
}
```

I need the last glue code.

Comment: i think @Fatmuemoo gave you the best solution, however your code will run if you add this `$this->view->bodyAttrs=$this->_makeBodyAttribs($this->idBody, $this->classesBody);` to the end of your actions. Also in your function `isset` should be replaced with `!empty` else it does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got one better for ya:

```
<?php
class My_View_Helper_Attribs extends Zend_View_Helper_HtmlElement
{

    public function attribs($attribs) {
        if (!is_array($attribs)) {
            return '';
        }
        //flatten the array for multiple values
        $attribs = array_map(function($item) {
           if (is_array($item) {
                return implode(' ', $item)
           }
           return $item;
        }, $attribs);
        //the htmlelemnt has the build in function for the rest
        return $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
    }
}
```

in your controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    //notice it is $this->view and not just $this
    $this->view->bodyAttribs= array('id' => 'someId', 'class' => array("wide","dark"));
}

public function loginAction()
{
    $this->view->bodyAttribs['id'] = "someId2";
    $this->view->bodyAttribs['class'] = array();
}
```

in your view script:

```
<body <?= $this->attribs($this->bodyAtrribs) ?>>
```